# Azure Stream Analytics to CosmosDB with partition key error

Tags: azure

I am receiving the following error when trying to connect my Azure Stream Analytics job to a CosmosDb output with a partition key.

> Error connecting to Cosmos DB Database: Invalid or no matching
>   collections found with collection pattern 'containername/{partition}'.
>   Collections must exist with case-sensitive pattern in increasing
>   numeric order starting with 0..

My container setup looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLdOP.png)
My output setup looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omcJK.png)

I have verified that I can manually add documents to the database and the partition is identified correctly and looks normal when viewed in DataExplorer.

NOTE: I read that partitions used to only be available on the "Unlimited" option but there is no longer a distinction and partitions are supported by default. If this is a misunderstanding, can you explain what options I do need to enable at setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a response from Microsoft support that specifying the partition via the "{partition}" token pattern is no longer supported by Azure Stream Analytics.  Furthermore, writing to multiple containers from ASA in general has been deprecated.  Now, if ASA outputs to a CosmosDb with a partition configured, Cosmos should automatically take care of that on its side.

> after discussion with our ASA developer/product group team, the
>   collection pattern such as  MyCollection{partition} or
>   MyCollection/{partition}  is no longer supported. Writing to multiple
>   fixed containers is being deprecated and it is not the recommended
>   approach for scaling out the Stream Analytics job
>   [...]
>   In summary, you can define the collection name simply as "apitraffic".
>   You don't need to specify any partition key as we detect it
>   automatically from Cosmos DB.